# Discontinuous function on Q

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

let $ f_n :X \rightarrow R $ be sequence of continuous function on complete metric space $(X,d)$, which convergence pointwisely to $ f: X\rightarrow R  $ mean that $ f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ $ \forall_x \in X$
I have to prove that set of continuity points is dense in $(X,d)$. I did it using Baire theorem, but I also have to prove that assumption of complete metric space is necessary.
There is a hint that I should use $(Q,d_e)$ as a metric space to find a counterexample. So I started to think about a function which is uncontinuous in every point. I set $Q$ in a string  $q_{n}$ then take $f(q_{n})=1/n$ and as a function $f_{m}$ take any continuous function(I was thinking about linear, but how to create such?)  such that  $ f_{m}(q_{n})=1/n$ for  $n=1,2,...,m$ Then $f_{m}$ converges pointwisely to $f$.
Any hints? Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Yes, you're taking a good approach. I think you are describing the function  used in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis*, Example 7.4, pg. 77-78. It's [available at Google books](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Analysis.html?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC). It will furnish the counterexample you need.

Comment: On further thought, your construction  is similar to the link above, but not the same. Regardless, it should work as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I have one concern regarding the example from the book. When it comes to the $min(1/n,1/q+2/n^2(x-p/q))$ for $x\in (p/q-1/2n^2,p/q)$. I just don't get it how we are getting the chart, as we get closer with $x$ to $ p/q-1/2n^2$ $f_n(x) \rightarrow min(1/n,1/q-1)$ so according to a chart from page 79, how do we get a straight line on $1/5$ cause $min(1/n,1/q-1)=1/q-1$ Where am I making some silly mistakes ?

Comment: Ah. yes, the definition for the "left hand sides of the spikes" seem off. The "min" should be a "max", correct?

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more explain it more precisely. The first 'part' of the spike should be 'drawn' by min, with $x\in( p/q-1/2n^,p/q)$. We want $f$ to be continuous so $ limx\rightarrow p/q-1/2n^2$ $f_n(x)$, we should get $1/n$ as the spike starts there but with $x\rightarrow p/1-1/2n^2$ we get, $min(1/n,1/q-1) = (1/q -1)<0 $ So in my point of view is uncontinuous  When I use max instead of min it is ok.

Comment: You're welcome. (You have some tough homework problems!)